# How do I change the map size on bing maps in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps

I'm looking at the Api and cant figure what option to make my map size smaller?
Anyone?

Comment: Anything you tried that is not working? Code?

Answer (score 4):

This worked well for me to create a small map:

```
<div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; position: relative;"></div>
```

The key part being **position: relative**

Answer (score 1):

It should be like so:

```
$("#mapID").width("400px").height("300px");
```

You would, of course, change the ID and sizes to the correct ones.

Edit: Yup. Works. Worth mentioning, the default ID for the embedded Bing map is just "map".